# Copy constructor for cursors?

Tags: android, cursor

I am trying to create a temporary cursor that can iterate over my data set while leaving the data member cursor in place but when I move my temporary cursor it also moves the primary cursor because it appears the temp is created as a reference to the primary cursor.  Is there any way around this?

```
Cursor tempCurs = this.cursor;
tempCurs.moveToNext() // This also moves this.cursor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cursor is a interface so making a copy constructor of it may be difficult. It sounds like all you really want to do is rememeber where you were so instead of using a copy you may consider keeping an int variable around of its [current position](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getPosition%28%29) then restoring the [previous position](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPosition%28int%29).

Comment: I could do that but I'm wondering if moveToPosition(int position) is actually in constant time or if it calls moveToNext/Previous a lot because I would like to avoid that.  I am unpacking the source now so I should have an answer to that question soon.

Comment: Its in the [code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java;h=c5921343ab9f04fe72a691cda6eb7d0c47dc438d;hb=HEAD). The short answer is constant time.

Comment: Guess that's a faster way to look up something simple like this lol.  You are right and thanks.  BTW it's actually in [AbstractCursor.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/database/AbstractCursor.java;h=a5e5e46cd599040c464f00df22bb9da107a0507d;hb=HEAD)